# How to calculate population in Excel if we only know the population growth rates and the starting population?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given this information:
The population in 2006 was 20,000,000.

and this information:

```
in 2007: the growth rate was 2.492035
in 2008: the growth rate was 1.733324
in 2009: it was 0.3956944
```

How can I create a function, which gives me the exact population numbers for 2007, 2008 and 2009?

I have tried some functions but they gave me false numbers.

Comment: Are you asking how to do multiplication?

Comment: Yes, I cannot use Excel, unfortunately.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? And what was the outcome? What was the expected outcome? And....are you not dealing with the `Floating Point Precision` explained [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much, this was my problem.

Comment: Forget Excel, what do you get when you plug things into a simple hand calculator? It seems that your question isn't really about Excel so much as basic mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

well, it's either column C or column D

[image: 0]

here is the sheet: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18lGV-xKOlrLnQDlDgNgKw7gph9KccAGvCfRsyP2FAdI/edit#gid=0)**

formula is: **(2006population * 2007rate) + 2006population = 2007population**